# Comment upvote color scheme

Tags: bug, design

Currently, comments with about >35 upvotes have the same upvote-counter color as that of <5 upvotes (which is some shade of gray). Shouldn't more upvoted comments have a more prominent counter color like it's done on SO?
Meta and workplace currently seem to follow this weird scheme.

I'm tagging this a bug. Please edit if you feel otherwise.

Comment: Yep, it's a dupe.